# ChartJS : chartjs-plugin-datalabels The value is in the wrong place

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I am using the datalabels plugin And ChartJs
I want the value to be right above the chart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cuyu.png)

```
 plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          backgroundColor: function(context) {
            return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
          },
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'top',
          clamp :true,
          display:'auto'
        }
        
      },
```

this is my ChartOption

Comment: Show your code. it's needed to advice

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi My code is as above

Comment: I mean working sample. you can create working snippet here by pressing `<>`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Unfortunately, the numbers are out of the box

Comment: You can use subset of your items. As you know without working sample it is really hard to solve your problem

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I uploaded a sample image of the output at the top of the page

Comment: I got your question. You need to create a working sample with subset of your data and then I can help you to find the problem.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi How i create a working sample ??

Comment: press `<>` button and you will see html , JavaScript and CSS part. then paste your html CSS and JavaScript code. Note that you also can add CDN (for example chart.js in html part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scriptable function for the `offset` parameter, only downside is that this is evaluated only at the beginning and not after the animations are done so you will need to disable animations because otherwise the labels get pushed up

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    animation: false,
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        backgroundColor: function(context) {
          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
        },
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        clamp: true,
        display: 'auto',
        offset: (ctx) => {
          const {
            datasetIndex,
            dataIndex,
            chart
          } = ctx;
          const data = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).data;

          return data[dataIndex].y - chart.chartArea.top - 22;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
</body>
```